# Why are variables not working with Get-Aduser in powershell?

Tags: powershell, variables, get-aduser

Looking for a little explanation as to why this isn't working and what I might be doing wrong.  Any Help would be great!

Expected Results :
BSMITH

`Get-Aduser -filter {(givenname -eq "Bob") -and (surname -eq "Smith"))} | select-object SamAccountName`

Result :
BSMITH

Works Fine.  Good to go

---

Expected Result :
BSMITH

```
$textbox_FirstName = "Bob"
$textbox_LastName = "Smith"

Get-Aduser -filter {(givenname -eq "$textbox_FirstName.text") -and (surname -eq "$textbox_LastName.text")} | select-object SamAccountName
```

Result : (Blank Nothing)

I have tried `givenname -eq "$textbox_FirstName.text"` without quotes, without .text, with no quotes at all. Still no results :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variables are of the type `string` they don't have a `.text` property, in addition adding double quotes to your variable would expand the variable and concatenate `.text`:

```
$textbox_FirstName = "Bob"
"$textbox_FirstName.Text" => Bob.Text
```

Any of these options should give you the output you expect:

```
Get-Aduser -Filter {GivenName -eq $textbox_FirstName -and Surname -eq $textbox_LastName}
```

```
Get-Aduser -Filter "GivenName -eq '$textbox_FirstName' -and Surname -eq '$textbox_LastName'"
```

```
Get-Aduser -LDAPFilter "(&(GivenName=$textbox_FirstName)(Surname=$textbox_LastName))"
```

Comment: Ultimately this is what my final code looked like. Which is a little more outside the scope of the original question.  But your answer certainly got me on the correct path.  Thank you very much for your help!!

```$textbox_psOutput.Text = Get-Aduser -Filter {(Surname -eq $Textbox_Lastname.Text -and GivenName -eq $Textbox_FirstName.Text)} | Select-Object SamAccountName | Out-String```

Comment: Happy to help @KyleMason